# How do I select a start-node for an Umbraco content picker without hard coding the ID

Tags: umbraco

I'm building an Umbraco content picker for some back end customisation like this

```
              {
              label: 'Select Product Category',
              description: 'This will be some really useful description for the picker when its written.',
              view: 'contentpicker',
              config: {
                  multiPicker: "0",
                  entityType: "Document",
                  startNode: {
                      query: "",
                      type: "content",
                      id: 1069
                  },
                  filter: "",
                  minNumber: 0,
                  maxNumber: 5
              },
              value: $scope.cat
          }
```

I'm guessing that instead of the id:1069 I can do *something* with the filter. Suppose I know the node will be named "Foo" - can I do something like filter:"/foo" and if so, what do I do with the ID?

Comment: Can you extend/complete the explanation? I guess this code is part of the configuration for a prevalue in a custom property editor, right?

Comment: The startnode should probably a configurable setting right? You can achieve this by adding fields to the package.manifest https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Tutorials/creating-a-property-editor/part-2